# Xquery ERROR err:XPDY0002: undefined value for variable $skill

Tags: xquery-sql, exist-db, xquery-3.0

I am trying to use xquery for a project and I cannot see why this query is not working. It gives me the following error:

```
err:XPDY0002:  undefined value for variable $skill
```

I am new to xquery and I am using EXIST DB as a database and I have tried using base x db and this works there perfectly. Is there anything i am missing in existdb? Any help would be appeciated.

```
for $endorsement in doc('/db/users.xml')/LOUser/Endorsements
for $endorsed_skill in $endorsement/Skills
let $skill := $endorsed_skill/text()
for $user in doc('/db/users.xml')/LOUser/User[@URL = $endorsement/URL2/text()]
let $Name := $user/Name/text()
where not($user/Skills/text() = $skill)/* I am getting the error here*/
group by 
$Name, $skill
return {$Name}
```

Comment: Not sure what your last line means `<Answer3> {$Name} </Answer3>`

Comment: I am just returning some Name